# I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have eliminated $y$ and have done this question in terms of $x$, then I solved the $x$ terms, collected like terms and did some elimination. After that, I made an auxiliary equation, founded roots and solved $x$ base $c$. The answer I'm getting is totally different from the book. I'm currently using Dennis G. Zill book 9th edition. Following is the book's answer.

\begin{align}x &= A + Bt + Ce^t + te^t \\
y &= -A — B — Bt - Ce^t - te^t + e^t\end{align}

[image]

Comment: Can you type out this question using MathJax? This shows your seriousness towards the question. If you can't give time to your question, why would anyone solve it for you?

Comment: If you don't know how to use MathJax, [this tutorial will help you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/421580)

Answer (score 1):

You are fine up to $D^3x- D^2x= e^t$.

Immediately after that you have "m^3- m^2= 0".
I presume that you are saying that the "associated homogeneous equation", $D^3x- D^2x= 0$ has "characteristic equation" $m^3- m^2= 0$.

Then you say "$m_1= 1$, $m_2= 0$".  That is *true* but not the entire story!
$m^3- m^2= m^2(m- 1)= 0$ so m= 0 is a **double** root!  The general solution to the associated homogeneous equation is $x_C= C_1e^t+ C_2e^{0t}+ C_3te^{0t}= C_1e^t+ C_2+ C_3t$.

Now, because the "non-homogeneous part" of this equation is $e^t$, you tried a "specific solution" of the form $Ae^t$.  That **can't possibly** work, because you already know that $Ae^t$ will give 0.  Changing the coefficient will still only give 0.  The same is true of $Ate^t$.

So try $x(t)= At^2e^t$.